# How to handle an exception correctly

Tags: c#, exception

I have an xmlbuilder utility class which calls a couple of methods to build an xml file

```
       public XMLBuilder(String searchVal)
        {
            this.searchVal = searchVal;

            try
            {
                getData();
                returnedData = processDataInToOriginalFormat();
                WriteBasicTemplate();
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                //If this is thrown then there was an error processing the HTTP request for MSO data.
                //In this case then i should avoid writing the xml for concordance.
                serviceAvailable = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Could not connect to the required Service.");

            }
            catch (NoDataFoundException ndfe)
            {
                //propegate this back up the chain to the calling class
                throw;
            }
```

`processDataInToOriginalFormat();` this is a method in a class which causes an exception if the service is not available and i have propagated the exception back to here to deal with. I was going to try and set a boolean flag to indicate whether to write a certain bit of xml. If the flag is false then dont write it.

I forgot however that exceptions stop programme flow and now i realise this isnt possible as if an exception occurs the rest of the code doesn't resume. how can i get around this? just add the `WriteBasicTemplate();` call in to my catch clause?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your code is somewhat confusing and as it's not obvious what "serviceAvailable = false" will do, it's hard to give detailed tips. The general rule of excetion handling is, to catch (and not rethrow) them, if you really know what to do with them and how to fix the problem. I you don't know that or the program will be in a state where it cannot continue working, let the exception go through and let your program crash.

In your case I might structure the code like this:

```
        try
        {
            returnedData = processDataInToOriginalFormat();
            // put code here which should only be executed in
            // case of no exception
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            // do what ever is required to handel the problem
            MessageBox.Show("Could not connect to the required Service.");
        }
        // code which should be executed in every case
        WriteBasicTemplate();
```

You shoudl also look at the "finally"-block. Depending on your requirements, you should WriteBasicTemplate in such a block. But I would probably not do so in your case. It's rather used for resource cleanup or something like that.

Comment: surely to propogate the exception to somewhere more suitable for dealing with it you need to rethrow? The finally clause solves all my problems too btw, and sorry for making logic hard to follow i had to remove busienss data

Comment: If you don't catch it at all, you don't need to rethrow it. ;-) But sometimes one has to catch the exception to decide whether it can be handled or not. And then you have to rethrow it of course. That was the point I tried to make explicit.